# How to use external library project in main project

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I am working with online recharge application and I want to create a Facebook type slide out and slide-in for that I want to use external project. Now I want to link that both. How to do that? I had tried to set properties to external project "is library" and in my project I added that library but it shows an error like a cross mark on library in main project properties.
What to do now?

Comment: Add external project to your build path.

Comment: You just need to import existing project into eclipse which you want to use as library project and then by going to properties of the other project -->then Android -->choose project from library section --> Click apply.

Comment: i had tried all things but now it's showing error that library file apk not found.

Answer (score 0):

In Library project, click right button -> properties -> Android -> check is library.

And in your project that you want to include this proyect, right button -> properties -> Android -> Add the other project.

Comment: i tried but it showing red mark on library

Answer (score 0):

Try to move both source and library in the same eclipse workspace. Might because of this it is showing red cross mark at library.

Comment: no i tried it but not working still showing that red mark